# Extraction list string from list

Tags: list-manipulation

Given the list:

```
list = {a > 0, b > 0}
```

I would like to get:

> {"a", "b"}

but I just can not find an efficient way to do it.

Some idea? Thank you!

Comment: What can we find in the list in general?

Comment: Maybe `ToString /@ list[[All, 1]]` ?